# Error using Mail::Sendmail to send email from perl script using a windows machine

Tags: windows, perl, email, sendmail

I have a simple test script for sending an email to myself using the cpan module Mail::Sendmail.  I am operating on a Windows machine using Strawberry Perl and through the command line, everything seems fine.  I am receiving an error that says `connect to localhost failed (No connection could be made because the target machine refused it.)`

My script is:

```
use Mail::Sendmail qw(sendmail %mailcfg);
$mailcfg{from} = 'dhagan@idatech.com';

print "Testing Mail::Sendmail version $Mail::Sendmail::VERSION\n";
print "Default server:  $Mail::Sendmail::mailcfg{smtp}->[0]\n";
print "Default sender:  $Mail::Sendmail::mailcfg{from}\n";

%mail = (   To      =>  'dhagan@email.com',
            From    =>  'dhagan@email.com',
            Message =>  'Test!'

        );

sendmail(%mail) or die $Mail::Sendmail::error;

print "OK.  Log says:\n", $Mail::Sendmail::log;
```

Is there any reason this would occur?

Comment: Use a network sniffer like [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) to record the SMTP submission. Provide the log.

Comment: You don't ask `Mail::Sendmail::error` for its status?

Comment: Ahhh.  The die statement I had was misleading me.  I will make adjustments to my question now!

Comment: you have a mail server running on localhost, I hope? And sendmail installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Mail::Sendmail is configured to send the mail to the localhost, but you are not running an SMTP server there.

You have to configre a suitable server - see the help.

```
 Default SMTP server(s)
       This is probably all you want to configure. It is usually done
       through $mailcfg{smtp}, which you can edit at the top of the
       Sendmail.pm file.  This is a reference to a list of SMTP servers.
       You can also set it from your script:

       "unshift @{$Mail::Sendmail::mailcfg{'smtp'}} , 'my.mail.server';"

       Alternatively, you can specify the server in the %mail hash you
       send from your script, which will do the same thing:

       "$mail{smtp} = 'my.mail.server';"
```